# WX_DECLARE_HASH_MAP in header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, hashmap, wxwidgets

In my `Visual Studio 2010` solution, I have a project written in `C++`. I used `wxwidgets3.0.2` library in the project and have the following line in one of my C++ files and it compiles well.

`WX_DECLARE_HASH_MAP (wxString,INode*,wxStringHash,wxStringEqual,IEval);`

Now, I need to access the `class IEval` in another `cpp` file. I tried declaring the above statement in the class definition in the header file. But I cannot access the class from another file. Can anyone help me in declaring the hash map so that I can access it across files.

EDIT:

Consider my header, file including the above said statement,`Class1.h` is as follows:

```
class Class1
{
   public:
    int GetCount();
    bool MapExist();
    WX_DECLARE_HASH_MAP (wxString,INode*,wxStringHash,wxStringEqual,IEval);

 private:
  int ent_val;
   int Openfile();
}
```

I can acess all member variables/functions from `Class1.cpp`. Now in `Class2.cpp`, I created an object of class Class1,say c1. Now on trying to access the members using `.` operator(VS lists all the possible members that can be called on entering `ctrl+space`. But IEval is not listed here), it says IEval is not defined.

I tried by defining the map in the header file but not in ths class. Even though I couldnt get the values stored in the map,it was possible to declare  c1.IEval in Class2.cpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you're writing new code you should really be using `std::unordered_map<>` instead of wxWidgets legacy macros.

Second, if you absolutely need to use `WX_DECLARE_HASH_MAP()`, then you need to realize that it declares an `IEval` **type**, not a variable with this name. You can then declare your map `IEval my_map;` or whatever.

Comment: i have edited the question accordingly. And i need to use wxwidgets itself